# Checking condition for all roots of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, algorithms

A couple of months ago I found this problem, and I think I will never find theory which will help me solving it, on my own, so I'm asking for a help. It's very interesting, I think:

> For a given polynomial $p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}p_kz^k$, where $n\le 20$ and $p_0,...,p_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$ decide if we have: $$p(z)=0 \Rightarrow|z|<1$$

By "decide" I mean to suggest efficient decision algorithm. Is there any theorem which can be helpful here? I guess finding all roots of $p$ (don't even know if it's possible) isn't the way to solve it. I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Basically you want to see if the polynomial has a solution, this is inside the unit disc, right? Have you tried to apply Rouché's Theorem?

Comment: @dado: Looks like he wants to see if _all_ $k$ roots are inside the unit disc.

Comment: http://fbhs.snnu.edu.cn/kcwz/all/dianzijiaoan/chn7/7.9.pdf.

Might be helpful. And do try for $p_1=p_2=..p_n=1$ .

Comment: @Henning Makholm: that's exactly what I asked! Rouché's Theorem should work anyway, although the answer will depend on the values $p_k$'s.

Comment: @dado: But $20\ge n$, it should work for any $n$ anyway.(If Rouche's theorem is used).

Comment: @Inceptio: in fact, I did not say anything about $n$, but about the specific coefficients ($p_k$'s) of the polynomials.

Comment: @dado: Right. I meant, the statement has to be generalized $n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [argument principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) lets you count the number of zeroes (with multiplicity) of a holomorphic function inside some closed contour such as the unit circle by evaluating a contour integral. Since the integral will always be a multiple of $2\pi i$ this is fairly easy to do this numerically (because you know in advance how much precision you need).

Since you know the polynomial has exactly $n$ roots in total, what you want to know is is $n$ is also the number of roots inside the unit circle.

Comment: thanks. I've read something about contour integrals and these were new things for me, but very interesting and I've learned a lot. But still don't know how can I count integrals numerically. I mean, I know but not in case of complex functions. Any hint how to start?

Comment: @xan: There's an expression for contour integrals in terms of plain old real integrals (one for the real part of the result, another for the imaginary part). This can be evaluated numerically just like any other real integral.